# Passing pointer-to-enum to pointer-to-int output parameter

Tags: c, casting, enums

I have code similar to the following:

```
void generateInt(int *result)
{
  /* chosen by fair dice roll*/
  *result = 1;
}

typedef enum colour
{
  RED,
  GREEN,
  BLUE
} COLOUR;

int main(int, char**)
{
  COLOUR col, col2;
  int i;

  generateInt(&i);
  col = (COLOUR)i;

  generateInt((int*)(&col2));

  return 0;
}
```

After the second call to `generateInt`, are `col` and `col2` both guaranteed to be equal to `GREEN`? I know the first version setting `col` is legal, but I don't know whether it's defined what happens if you cast pointer-to-enum to pointer-to-int, and then assign through the pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's certainly *not* OK. You have no reason to believe that the underlying type of the enum is `int`, and thus casting the pointers may be wildly inappropriate.

Why not just change the function?

```
void generateInt(COLOUR * c)
{
    *c = GREEN;
}
```

Comment: Because, in reality, I'm loading a structure which has been written to disk. `generateInt` is actually a generic function which reads the next (integer) field from the data obtained from a file.

Comment: @Chowlett Such an implementation would not be portable.  What about machines with different `sizeof(int)` or byte order?  Why not just use a consistent format for storage, and have the loader function set the value of an enum?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a proper way :

```
void generateInt(COLOUR * c)
{
    //Roll number given here
    switch(roll_result)
    {
      case 0 :
        *c = RED;
      break;
      case 1 :
         *c = GREEN;
      break;          
      case 2 :
         *c = BLUE;
      break;
      //...
      default :
      break;
   }
}
```